Newly uploaded app cannot be installed from playstore
enter image description herecann't install "AppName". please contact support.
I have previous build in playstore. when I have uploaded version 2.0.0 its updating fine. but I mistakenly uploaded a build with some wrong setting which I have attached in the bottom as 3.0.0. Then when this issue occurred I have placed a new build with correct version number and build. But still when I am using my production apk with 3.0.0 as checking for update its updating to 3.0.1 but when my production app which is 2.0.0 I try to update that is saying the above line after installing. Now I have some users with 2.0.0 installed in their phone. Now how can I solve that?
in the app level build.gradle at first when I am building the appBundle I missed
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '11'//here
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if(flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '3.0.1'//here
}

to change the version name and build . thoughe in the same app level build.gradle I have added version code and version name in the 3.0.0. I am assuming that step I forgot from there the issue started . Now My question is How can I fix the issue. Tried several stack overflow solution but not worked for me. Any one with a detailed suggestion will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

can you share the ss from playstore console  App bundle explorer, listing the app version code and name for all these 3 build you talk about. And the error you mentioned normally happen when you are trying to update app and both the version have different signing key. But if you can share the ss, it will be great

@Ultranmus brother I have added the screen shot. any more thing u need??

Can you also check SHA1 key for 2.0.0 and 3.0.0

Just curious , when you are testing the apk, you are downloading the universal apk from playstore console right? Because if one verison is from local build and other one is a universal apk from playstore. It will not work as when you upload app to playstore it's SHA1 changes. Meaning the local build and uploaded one will have different SHA1 so if you are testing like that it will throw this error.

@Ultranmus I am using the local build and checking that with play store . But I am using keystore same for both the case. still you are saying it will not make the difference???

Dude. Try to check with build from playstore. From the  App bundle explorer. Download all these 3 version and test with them in your mobile. Playstore do auto signing for you over your own signing, so SHA1 for local build and playstore will be different. And difference in SHA1 causes the error you mentioned. So first please download universal apk from app bundle explorer. Try 2.0.0 first and then try to update it to 3.0.0.Do not use local build. Of it works there will be no prblm for users in Updating when they try to update from playstore
